# cURL HTTPS follow redirection

Tags: php, curl

I had the below code working to get a HTTP url follow the redirect and then pass back the new page url it was on.

```
// Follow URL
private function follow_url($url) {
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // return headers 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch ); 

    $output = $header["url"];
    return $output;
}
```

I am now trying to get it to work with HTTPS but it does not follow on it stops at the inputted URL.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following options:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
```